# Error with Postgres Database Authentication with Data Studio

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

I am trying to connect my postgres database to Data Studio and I received the following error:

> Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request. Error ID:1b7b6c50.

I entered in the same credentials that I used (successfully) when I connected my postgres database to Tableau, and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

```
 Host Name or IP: localhost
 Port: 5432
 Database: WU
 Username: postgres
 Password: [my correct password]
```

While troubleshooting, I also tried entering in `1` `::1` and `:1` for the host name, and got the same error. However, when I entered `local` as the host name, it seemed like Data Studio did some thinking before shooting me a different error. The new error said:

> Can't reach the host. Please double check your connection parameters. Learn more about database connectors here.
> Error ID: 079b22f8"

Does anyone have an explanation as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: Give it a try with host=127.0.0.1  which is the same thing as localhost

Comment: try `127.0.0.1` or configure the `pg_hba.conf` and change ipv4 address to `0.0.0.0:0` and postgres should listen to accept connection

Comment: AFAIK google datastudio is cloud solution, so it don't understand `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Or there is some desktop app?

Comment: Thank you @Slumdog I tried entering your suggestion, but I got the same error as before "Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request."

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @dwir182. Would you be able to provide more details about how I should go about this? I read postgres's documentation about the pg_hba.conf file and found this article that mentioned making a backup copy of it before altering it (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/configure-postgresql-accept-connections.htm) but I want to make sure doing so won't break the connection I already have set up with Tableau (or cause other unexpected issues for me). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist some ips inorder for google data studio to connect to postgres. Here's the [google support](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010?hl=en)

Comment: I had a similar problem connecting to Azure Microsoft SQL Server, whitelisting helped.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this - I think there is something wrong with adding authorised networks IP addresses for your instance in google console. I named each address ds1, ds2 etc. and had to add them one by one. Adding all 12 then clicking 'save' didn't seem to save them.

Even when I had them all listed in console, it would not authenticate.

As a last gasp attempt I tried a v12 instance (was on v14) but made no difference.

Finally I ran the IP updates as a gcloud command:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [instance] --authorized-networks=64.18.0.0/20,64.233.160.0/19,66.102.0.0/20,66.249.80.0/20,72.14.192.0/18,74.125.0.0/16,108.177.8.0/21,173.194.0.0/16,207.126.144.0/20,209.85.128.0/17,216.58.192.0/19,216.239.32.0/19
```

This then let me in but only on the v12 instance, not the v14.

In summary, stick to v12 and run a gcloud command above.